# How to modify a office.js react element in outlook addin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, outlook-addin, office-addins

Using the new office.js, specifically the ReactJS Scaffolding provided by the MS Team.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/#/controls/web

If I create multiple react elements in the standard react return, such as,

```
<TextField label="Date:" disabled styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }} defaultValue="Wednesday, May 8, 2019" />
<TextField label="Date2:" disabled styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }} defaultValue="Wednesday, May 9, 2019" />
<TextField label="Date3:" disabled styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }} defaultValue="Wednesday, May 10, 2019" />
```

How do I then access a specific UI element, such as Date programmatically and modify the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object reference for the component, then you can access its properties. E.g.:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component<any> {
    private myTextBox = React.createRef<TextFieldBase>();
    
    constructor(props: any) {

        super(props);
    }
    
    readAProperty() {
      console.log(`Current value: {this.myTextBox.current.value}`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <TextField label="Date:" 
          disabled styles={{ root: { width: 300 } }} 
          defaultValue="Wednesday, May 8, 2019" 
          componentRef={this.myTextBox}
          />
        );
    }
}
```